# Xamarin databinding MVVM not rendering text content on UI

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

This is my first test with MVVM in Xamarin. I am trying to display a list of objects (examples) noted as ExampleList provided by a web API. It receives the correct data and object structure with the api & app models being pretty much 1:1.

When the page loads it presents all 9 correct elements though the text for these elements doesnt display. I know this data is correct because when an element is clicked it displays its fields of the object within a display alert.

I am certain the issue is with the markup as you can see below it is declared as:
object.property , usually i would declare this as just property without the object but when doing this method the app will not compile showing the following error:

```
"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   XFC0045 Binding: Property "ID" not found on "App2.ViewModels.ExampleListViewModel". App2    E:\App2\App2\App2\Views\ExampleListPage.xaml    22  "
```

As far as my understanding it should be assuming and binding the parent of the properties object is an example from the view model.

I have also attempted to manually declare the objects fields within the ViewModel and this does compile but has similar results of not displaying the text.

The strange part about this issue is while the application is running the text cell property declaration can be changed from Object.Property to Property and will display the text but again when recompiling will produce the same error stated above.

The code for the xaml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App2.Views.ExampleListPage"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:App2.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:ExampleListViewModel" 
             Title="Example List">


    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:ExampleListViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ListView x:Name="listView" Margin="20" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElement, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding ExampleList}"
              RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding ID}" Detail="{Binding Example.Desc}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

The code behind for the page is as follows:

```
using App2.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace App2.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ExampleListPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ExampleListPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new ExampleListViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

The view model for this page is as follows:

```
using App2.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App2.ViewModels
{
    public class ExampleListViewModel : BindableObject // < this is needed for mvvm
    {
        public ExampleListViewModel()
        {
            //buttons delcared here also need to be declared below as icommands
            ListElementSelect = new Command(ElementSelect);
            RefreshCommand = new Command(OnRefresh);
            AddElement = new Command(OnAddElement);

            OnRefresh(); // unsure if ok to call here
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// private elements are here
        /// </summary>
        private example _example;
        private List<example> _exampleList = new List<example>();
        private bool _isBusy = false;
        private example _selectedElement;

        /// <summary>
        /// public elements are here
        /// </summary>
        /// 


        // this does fix compile error but doesn't display text still
        //public int ID {
        //    get => this.Example.ID;
        //}
        //private string _desc;
        //public string Desc {
        //    get => this.Example.Desc;
        //}

        public example SelectedElement
        {
            get => _selectedElement;
            set
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Selected", value.ID + value.Content, "x");
                    value = null;
                }
                _selectedElement = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public example Example
        {
            get => _example;
            set
            {
                _example = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Example));
            }
        }
        public List<example> ExampleList
        {
            get => _exampleList;
            set
            {
                _exampleList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ExampleList));
            }
        }
        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get => _isBusy;
            set
            {
                if (value == _isBusy) return;
                _isBusy = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsBusy));
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// button commands are here
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand ListElementSelect { get; }
        public ICommand RefreshCommand { get; }
        public ICommand AddElement { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// functions here
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        async void ElementSelect()
        {

        }

        async void OnAddElement()
        {

        }

        async void OnRefresh()
        {
            OnBusy();
            await Load(); // request list from API service
            await Task.Delay(2000); //artifical package delay
            OnBusy();
        }

        void OnBusy() // flip instance from true or false - for displaying loading symbol while performing requests
        {
            switch (IsBusy)
            {
                case true:
                    IsBusy = false;
                    break;
                case false:
                    IsBusy = true;
                    break;
            }
        }

        async Task Load()
        {
            string searchTerm = "";
            Expression<Func<example, bool>> searchLambda = x => x.Content.Contains("SearchTerm"); // instanciate searchLambda
            string stringLambda = searchLambda.ToString().Replace("SearchTerm", $"{searchTerm}"); //crashes here
            searchLambda = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda<example, bool>(new ParsingConfig(), true, stringLambda);
            ExampleList = await App.DataService.GetAllAsync<example>();

            //listView.ItemsSource = ExampleList;

        }
    }
}
```

and this is the example class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using App2.ViewModels;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace App2.Models
{
    public class example
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; //this does event things
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }

        public string WebLink { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore] // need newtonsoft
        public string Desc
        { // for list display, not transfered to backend
            get
            {
                return ID.ToString() + " - " + Content.ToString() + " - " + Status.ToString();
            }
        }

        public example(int id, string content, bool status, string webLink)
        { this.ID = id; this.Content = content; this.Status = status; this.WebLink = webLink; }

        public example() { }

        public string toString()
        {
            return ID.ToString() + " - " + Content.ToString() + " - " + Status.ToString() + " - " + WebLink.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: first, get rid of `x:DataType="viewmodels:ExampleListViewModel" `.  Second, change `Binding Example.Desc` to `Binding Desc`

Comment: Hi Jason, i know the example.Desc needed changing i was just trying to show the two different states one which i was trying to achieve and wouldnt compile and the other which would compile but didn't work. 

Removing the datatype tag as you mentioned did work but i am more curious as to why this was preventing text from not being displayed. if you could provide more information or a link to explain this that would be greatly appreciated. You have saved me from a lot of headache!

Comment: `DataType` gives VS and the compiler a hint about what type is used in the bindings, but it's not "smart" enough to realize that the BindingContext for each **row** in a ListView is different than the BindingContext for the entire page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to remove the page-level `x:DataType` attribute. You can inform the compiler of the DataType of the DataTemplate by specifying the `x:DataType` attribute on the DataTemplate itself (note that you'll need to add an `xmlns` reference for this to work, similar to your `xmlns:viewmodels` reference):

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="models:example">
     <TextCell Text="{Binding ID}" Detail="{Binding Example.Desc}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

As for the list not displaying any items, I would double-check that this line:

```
ExampleList = await App.DataService.GetAllAsync<example>();
```

is returning a non-empty list of items. Since you haven't included that method in your question, I can't make any assumptions about what it does.

And one final aside: you don't necessarily need to inherit `BindableObject` in your ViewModel for MVVM to work; just `INotifyPropertyChanged` will suffice.